# Running .jsp as .html file

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have created a jsp page which run fine when executed in tomcat.But when i change the extension of my file to .html it show nothing.
Is there any way where i can run .jsp with .html file extension

Comment: And why do you want that? JSP is a preprocessor for HTML. When browser requests a `.jsp` file, tomcat generates valid, static HTML from the templating rules. When browser requests  a `.html` file, it is served as it is. Do you want your URLs to have a `.html` extension instead of `.jsp`?

Comment: yes i want url extension to be .html

Comment: Then you need URL rewriting. The only way I can (yes, there could be simpler ways) think of is putting Apache as a reverse proxy (mod_proxy) **in front of** Tomcat and implementing URL rewrite rules (mod_rewrite) to rename `.jsp` to `.html`

Comment: thank u aitchnya i added <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> in web.xml and it worked fine

Comment: So there **was** a simpler method :-)

Comment: @jan5 A blackbox pen-tester sees .jsp and .do and knows the server is tomcat. You're doing their job for them by not masking this in some way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

add

```
         <servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
```

in web.xml

Comment: This works but I think this answer is neater: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21875973/387048

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I did get something working for a specific html page though (index.html)

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>IndexServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```