# CSS3PIE without PHP or modifying the .htaccess file

Tags: java, css, css3pie

My client is running a Java-based server with no PHP enabled and no access to the .htaccess file. I want to be able to serve CSS3PIE up to the server, and have it simply work. I would absolutely prefer not to use the JS version. How can I let Java serve up the file with the correct content type in much the way that PHP does?

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/x-component' );
include( 'PIE.htc' );
?>
```

This PHP file sets the header of the page to allow for `text/x-component` which in turn allows for HTC files in IE.

In short, are there any workarounds for using PIE.htc without .htaccess, PHP, or the JS files?

Comment: It should be easy to set content-type for .htc files, depends on which webserver you are running.

Comment: @enapupe I believe we're running Apache. I'm the front-end guy, so this is a bit beyond my typical scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaServer Pages (JSP) has page directives that are very similar to PHP. The following is equivalent to your PHP example:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/x-component" %><%@ include file="PIE.htc" %>
```

You can put that in any JSP file you like, for example a file named `pie.jsp`. That means you will need to point to the .jsp file in your CSS instead of the .htc file:

```
behavior: url(pie.jsp);
```

That should be all you need to do. However if you want to have the .htc file extension in your URLs instead of .jsp, then you could configure the Java application server to render .htc files as JSPs, and then put the above directives into a .htc file instead. See [Can you render a file without a .jsp extension as a JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507733/can-you-render-a-file-without-a-jsp-extension-as-a-jsp) for details.

---

### Documentation

**JSP page directive:** http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahj.html

**JSP include directive:** http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html

Comment: Perfect. Good explanation and solved my problem. I looked into writing the headers via a .jsp tag, but never figured it out for some reason, which is kind of frustrating because of how simple the solution is haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your apache configuration:

`AddType text/x-component .htc`

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I think that the Apache config goes hand in hand with the .htaccess file in that our clients server admins won't let us touch them. My goal is more to find a java-based workaround much the way that the PHP workaround works.