# Can we add *.html files instead of *.jsp in Spring 4 with tiles 3?

Tags: spring-4, tiles-3

I am trying to add *.html page in tiles definition, but it's displaying runtime exception, this page is static; but when i change extension from html to jsp, it works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running .jsp as .html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256122/running-jsp-as-html-file)

Answer (score 0):

add the following code

```
<servlet-mapping> <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name> <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> </servlet-mapping>
```

in web.xml