# getRequestDispatcher dispatching jsp but not html

Tags: html, jsp, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I am running google app engine and using JAVAEE.

I have a two filters but only one is configured with restrictions.

**WEB.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <filter>
        <filter-name>connexionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>AHSFilters.connexionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>restrictFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>AHSFilters.restrictFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>connexionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>restrictFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/client</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

1. I first login so I can go trough the first filter.
2. I change my url to `localhost:8080/client`

my connexion filter is as so:

```
    package AHSFilters;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    public class connexionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        if(session.getAttribute("sessionUser") != null)
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        if (req.getHeader("X-Requested-With") != null)
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        else
            req.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/").forward(request, response);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

my servlet is as so:

```
package AHSServlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet(
        name = "ClientServ",
        urlPatterns = {"/client"}
    )
public class ClientServ extends HttpServlet{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.getWriter().flush();
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/restrict/client/test.jsp").forward(request, response);;
    }
}
```

when my file is setted to `test.jsp` I go to the correct page, but when I rename it to `test.html` and of course change the path in `getRequestDispatcher` I get redirected to my login page (`/` route).

So I have to files `/restrict/client/test.jsp` i get the correct response
and `/restrict/client/test.html` I go back to the signin page.

I've tried putting a simple `hello` in `test.html` also tried with valid html page with the same result. Is there any settings I'm missing in order to allow html?

Where could it come from? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please add the code of your `AHSFilters.connexionFilter`

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala Done. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in order to do so you need little configuration. In `web.xml` write a configuration code

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

To understand better you can check

[Can you render a file without a .jsp extension as a JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507733/can-you-render-a-file-without-a-jsp-extension-as-a-jsp/21875973#21875973)

[Running .jsp as .html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256122/running-jsp-as-html-file)